# Python ImportError: No module named utils

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, debian

I am trying to run my python script in Debian but I keep getting the following error:

```
traceback (most recent call last):
    File "gluon/contrib/websocket_messaging.py", Line 96, in <module>
        import gluon.utils
ImportError: No module named utils
```

I've tried:

```
pip install gluon
```

Still didn't work. I also tried:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-gluon
```

but got

```
Unable to locate package python-gluon
```

Any help would be appreciated thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3-gluon

OR

pip3 install gluon
```

Comment: Oops I meant to write pip install gluon, which I've done. Also this will be using python2.7. I've used: sudo apt-get install python2.7-gluon but it says that it coudlnt find a matching distribution